# How to print lines with a certain length in a file(Python)

Tags: python, file

I am new to python. I have a document that has one random word per line. There are thousands of words in this file. I am trying to print only the words that are four letters long. I tried this:

```
f=open("filename.txt")
Words=f.readlines()
for line in f:
    if len(line)==4:
        print(line)
f.close()
```

But python is blank when I do this. I am assuming I need to strip the blank spaces as well, but when I did

```
f.strip()
```

I received an error stating that .strip() doesn't apply to list items. Any help is grateful. Thanks!

Comment: You can just iterate over f, no need for `readlines()`.

Comment: Specifically, once you read the entire file with `readlines()`, there's nothing left in it when you do `for line in f:`.

Answer (score 5):

'Python is blank' because you attempt to iterate over the file for a second time.

The first time is with `readlines()`, so when that iteration is finished you are at the end of the file. Then when you do `for line in f` you are already at the end of the file so there is nothing left over which to iterate. To fix this, drop the call to `readlines()`.

To do what you want to have, I would just do this:

```
with open('filename.txt') as f:
    for line in f:  # No need for `readlines()`
        word = line.strip()  # Strip the line, not the file object.
        if len(word) == 4:
            print(word)
```

---

Your other error occurs with `f.strip()` because `f` is a file object- but you only `strip` a string. Therefore just split the `line` on each iteration as shown in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
for line in Words:
```

instead of

```
for line in f:
```

Answer (score -1):

You want `line.strip()` because f is a file object, not a string.